# Materialize dropdown menu shows horizontal scrollbar rather than expanding past its parent when the text is longer. Anyone know why?

Tags: materialize

I seem to be able to find the question posted on here and google about the same issue in bootstrap, but i'm not able to find answers for the same issue in Materialize

I'm new to bootstrap and everything i've tried hasn't solved it. I'd be grateful if anyone knows why it's doing this and how to override it.

Thank you!

the live page is [here](http://action.focallocal.org)

i've set drop downs to fire on 'about' and 'profile'

the script:

```
    <script>
    var $ = jQuery;
    (function($){
        $(function(){

            $('.dropdown-button').dropdown({
                inDuration: 300,
                outDuration: 225,
                constrain_width: false,
                hover: false,
                alignment: 'right',
                gutter: 0,
                belowOrigin: true,
            });

            $('.button-collapse').sideNav({menuWidth: 240, activationWidth: 70});

        }); // end of document ready
    })(jQuery); // end of jQuery name space
</script>
```

nav bar:

```
    <nav>
    <div class="nav-wrapper">
        <a class="brand-logo hide-on-med-and-down left" href="http://focallocal.org">Focallocal</a>
        <ul class="hide-on-small-and-down left">
            <li class="text-icon">
                <a class="dropdown-button" href="http://about.focallocal.org" data-activates="nav-about" title="About Us">
                    <i class="mdi-action-info"></i>
                    <span>About Us</span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="text-icon">
                <a href="http:&#x2F;&#x2F;news.focallocal.org&#x2F;" title="Happy News">
                    <i class="mdi-device-brightness-high"></i>
                    <span>Happy News</span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="text-icon">
                <a href="http:&#x2F;&#x2F;action.focallocal.org&#x2F;" title="Action">
                    <i class="mdi-action-get-app"></i>
                    <span>Action Centre</span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="text-icon">
                <a href="http://activities.focallocal.org" title="Activities">
                    <i class="mdi-maps-directions-walk"></i>
                    <span>Activities</span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="text-icon">
                <a href="http:&#x2F;&#x2F;gather.focallocal.org&#x2F;" title="Gather">
                    <i class="mdi-image-flare"></i>
                    <span>&nbsp;Gather&nbsp;</span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="text-icon">
                <a href="http:&#x2F;&#x2F;shop.focallocal.org&#x2F;" title="Shop">
                    <i class="mdi-action-shop-two"></i>
                    <span>&nbsp;Shop</span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="text-icon">
                <a class="dropdown-button" href="#" data-activates="nav-projects" title="Projects">
                    <i class="mdi-action-info"></i>
                    <span>Projects</span>
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="right">
            <li class="text-icon">
                <a href="http://discuss.focallocal.org" target="_blank" title="Chat">
                    <i class="mdi-communication-dialpad"></i>
                    <span>Discuss</span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="text-icon">
                <a href="https://trello.com/invite/b/SwMdGGcX/dbf6c3cebca7e2214ac0df3a57b1881f/build-the-movement" target="_blank" title="Missions">
                    <i class="mdi-content-create"></i>
                    <span>Missions</span>
                </a>
            </li>
             <li class="text-icon">
                <a href="#" title="coming soon">
                    <i class="mdi-action-perm-media"></i>
                    <span>Profile</span>
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <ul id="user-dropdown" class="dropdown-content">

            <li><a href="http://news.focallocal.org/sign-in">Log in</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://news.focallocal.org/sign-up">Register</a></li>
        </ul>
        <a class="button-collapse" href="#" data-activates="nav-mobile"><i class="mdi-navigation-menu"></i></a>
    </div>
</nav>
```

dropdowns:

```
<ul id="nav-about" class="dropdown-content">
<li>
    <a href="http://about.focallocal.org">About Us</a>
</li>
<li>
    <a href="http://hire.focallocal.org">Hire Us</a>
</li>
<li>
    <a href="http://news.focallocal.org/the-focallocal-community-values/">Community Values</a>
</li>
<li>
    <a href="http://news.focallocal.org/faqs">F.A.Q</a>
</li>
<li>
    <a href="http://news.focallocal.org/about-andy-and-the-road-to-focallocal/">The Road to Focallocal</a>
</li>
<li>
    <a href="http://news.focallocal.org/are-we-sure-of-success/">Will we Succeed?</a>
</li>
<li>
    <a href="http://news.focallocal.org/category/in-the-news/">Focallocal in the news</a>
</li>
```

```
<ul id="nav-projects" class="dropdown-content">
<li>
    <a href="http://action.focallocal.org/">Action Center
    </a>
</li>
<li>
    <a href="http://brightertomorrowmap.com/">Brighter Tomorrow Map
    </a>
</li>
<li>
    <a href="http://morehappiness.focallocal.org/">More Happiness
    </a>
</li>
```

Comment: Something is adding an inline style on the unordered list that specifies the width explicitly: `<ul id="nav-about" class="dropdown-content active" style="position: absolute; top: 64px; left: 152px; opacity: 1; display: block; width: 92px;">` If you remove that via developer tools, the width of the parent should adjust to the width of the contents. So you need to find what's causing the in-line style to appear when the user clicks on the menu item.

Comment: thanks. after further research i found that materialie css script i called was setting this value and added this code to my css to override it

`dropdown-content{
   overflow: visible !important;
   overflow-y: visible;
   width: auto !important;
}`

that's worked. now i'm noticing it's also caused other changes site wide on my wordpress install, so i'm researching how to limit the materialize css to just the menu and not the rest of the site, it seems difficult as its an external css file so i can't add conditions as i usually would